# What do they mean saying "thumping through the brush"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I came across a phrase given by Lennon during his bed-in session. Here is the context

> Also, of course, we live with rattlesnakes.
>   You just can’t **go thumping through the brush**, thinking of what
>   you’re going to do tomorrow. You have to realize that you’re intruding
>   on their territory.

What does go thumping through the brush mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"To thump", as defined by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thump) is:

> to hit or beat something or someone and make a loud, deep sound
>
> to beat forcefully
>
> to walk or run with loud, heavy steps

Think of a male gorilla, thumping his chest.  Basically, it means to make a whole lotta noise, which is rather rude to the snakes if you're thumping or stomping around in their territory.